# How to scale an image in a GPUImage pipeline

Tags: objective-c, gpuimage

I need to scale an image as it is passed through a GPUImage pipeline. I am outputting the image to another file.

Here is is my simple pipeline:

```
UIImage *inputImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"8x8.png"]; // The WID.jpg example is greater than 2048 pixels tall, so it fails on older devices

sourcePicture = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:inputImage];

transformFilter = [[GPUImageTransformFilter alloc] init];
transformFilter.affineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0, 2.0);

[sourcePicture addTarget:transformFilter];
[transformFilter prepareForImageCapture];

[sourcePicture processImage];

UIImage *currentFilteredImage = [transformFilter imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput];

NSData *dataForPNGFile = UIImagePNGRepresentation(currentFilteredImage);

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSError *error = nil;
if (![dataForPNGFile writeToFile:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"filtered1.png"] options:NSAtomicWrite error:&error])
{
    return;
}
```

The input image is 8x8 pixels and I want to output an image at 16x16 pixels.

There are currently two issues with the above pipeline:

1) The output image size is still 8x8 pixels, although the original image has been scaled by 2.0, it has been cropped back to the original size.

2) The output image is blurred, this is the same effect I get in the iPhone photo App when viewing very small images. I think it is most likely a smoothing function being applied by default somewhere in the pipeline.

I want to just scale the input image without any smoothing so that the pixels remain sharp.

EDIT: By replacing

transformFilter.affineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0, 2.0);

with

[transformFilter forceProcessingAtSize:CGSizeMake(16.0, 16.0)];

I now have a scaled image at 16x16 pixels, but I still have the bluring of the image.

EDIT 2:

If I scale the 8x8 image to 320x320 then the result is identical to viewing the same 8x8 pixel image in the iPhone photo App. It is completely blurred out, pixels appear pinched with bright highlights at the pixel boundaries. This suggests that the issue is not with core GPUImage code but rather where GPUImage relies on core image for functionality.

Is there any way to scale using only GPUImage code and avoiding core image altogether?

EDIT 3: I posted the distortion issue on the GPUImage github project, you can read the full question and response [here](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/issues/1212)

The upshot is that I needed to set minFilter and magFilter texture params to GL_NEAREST instead of GL_LINEAR;

My final solution was to clone the GPUImagePicture class and in the initWithCGImage: selector change:

```
if (self.shouldSmoothlyScaleOutput)
        {
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
        }
```

to:

```
if (self.shouldSmoothlyScaleOutput)
        {
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
        }
        else
        {
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        }
```